# Distinct number of changes in real time data

Tags: for-loop, real-time, increment, labview

Hi I am taking in data in real time where the value goes from 1009 , 1008 o 1007 to 0. I am trying to count the number of distinct times this occurs, for example the snippet below should count 2 distinct periods of change.

```html
1008
1009
1008
0
0
0
1008
1007
1008
1008
1009
9
0
0
1009
1008
```

I have written a for loop as below but I can't figure out if the logic is correct as I get multiple increments instead of just the one

```html
if(current != previous && current < 100)
x++;
else 
x = x;
```

Comment: Is the 9 on the twelfth line of your example a typo?

Comment: no its not its noise from the instrument

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with the LabVIEW tag. Is this actually supposed to be LabVIEW code?

Your logic has a bug related to the noise you say you have - if the value is less than 100 and it changes (for instance from 9 to 0), you log that as a change. You also have a line which doesn't do anything (x=x), although if this is supposed to be LV code, then this could make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted here does not seem to make sense to me if I understand your goal.  My understanding is that you want to identify this specific pattern:

1009
1008
1007
0

And that any deviation from this sequence of numbers would constitute data that should be ignored.  To this end, you should be monitoring the history of the past 3 numbers.  In C you might write this logic in the following way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//Function to get the next value from our data stream.
int getNext(int *value) {

  //Variable to hold our return code.
  int code;

  //Replace following line to get gext number from the stream.  Possible read from a file?
  *value = 0;

  //Replace following logic to set 'code' appropriately.
  if(*value == -1)
    code = -1;
  else
    code = 0;

  //Return 'code' to the caller.
  return code;

}

//Example application for counting the occurrences of the sequence '1009','1008','1007','0'.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //Declare 4 items to store the past 4 items in the sequence (x0-x3)
  //Declare a count and a flag to monitor the occurrence of our pattern
  int x0 = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, count = 0, occurred = 0;

  //Run forever (just as an example, you would provide your own looping structure or embed the algorithm in your app).
  while(1) {

    //Get the next element (implement getNext to provide numbers from your data source).
    //If the function returns non-zero, exit the loop and print the count.
    if( getNext(&x0) != 0 )
         break;

    //If the newest element is 0, we can trigger a check of the prior 3.
    if(x0 == 0) {

      //Set occurred to 0 if the prior elements don't match our pattern.
      occurred = (x1 == 1007) && (x2 == 1008) && (x3 == 1009);
      if(occurred) {
        //Occurred was 1, meaning the pattern was matched.  Increment our count.
        count++;
        //Reset occurred
        occurred = 0;
      }

    //If the newest element is not 0, dont bother checking.  Just shift the elements down our list.
    } else {

      x3 = x2;  //Shift 3rd element to 4th position
      x2 = x1;  //Shift 2nd element to 3rd position
      x1 = x0;  //Shift 1st element to 2nd position

    }

  }

  printf("The pattern count is %d\n", count);

  //Exit application
  return 0;

}
```

Note that the getNext function is just shown here as an example but obviously what I have implemented will not work.  This function should be implemented based on how you are extracting data from the stream.

Writing the application in this way might not make sense within your larger application but the algorithm is what you should take away from this.  Essentially you want to buffer 4 elements in a rolling window.  You push the newest element into x0 and shift the others down.  After this process you check the four elements to see if they match your desired pattern and increment the count accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to count falling edges and you don't care about the specific level, and want to reject noise band or ripple in the steady state then just make the conditional something like

```
if ((previous - current) > threshold)
```

No complex shifting, history, or filtering required. Depending on the application you can follow up with a debounce (persistency check) to ignore spurious samples (just keep track of falling/rising, or fell/rose as simple toggling state spanning a desired number of samples).

Code to the pattern, not the specific values; use constant or adjustable parameters to control the value sensitivity.